# Style input underline when not focused

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm simple trying to theme a whole `mat-input`. I've made a custom color palette and changed every color in it to black and applied it:

```
$MPBlack: mat-palette($pBlack);
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($MPBlack, $MPBlack, $MPBlack);
@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);
```

I've tried and tried but no matter what I do the color of the underline changes only when I focus the input.

How do I theme the unfocused input??

While we're at it, how do I change the font color? And or background-color?

[image: Image of input]

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Code for what exactly @JoelJoseph

Comment: your css  code to override the theme styles and the html code on inspecting your element after render

Comment: I'm trying to use the theming function by angular. I know how to override css but I want to declare a theme.